# sharing a js functions between code in 2 files

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery code is divided file is divided over 2 files.

In one of the file, I define a function

```
function something(input){
  //does something
}
```

calling this function only works when the caller line is in the same file. But I need to call it from both files.

If I switch the function to the second file, again I get the same issue. The code in the same file can read it, but not the code in the other file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place your functions outside of `$(document).ready(function() { });` to give them global scope. Anything placed within it cannot be accessed from the outside.

You can then look into using a namespace to encapsulate your functions. This helps to avoid clutter of the global namespace.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a *namespace object*, which is shared between your files.

**fileA.js**

```
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {};

mynamespace.something = function(input) {
    // do something
};
```

**fileB.js**

```
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {};

mynamespace.something();
```

Comment: I'm using JQuery and each of my files start like this. Where do I put the namespace? Outside or inside the document ready? `$(document).ready(function() {
 
});`

Comment: @sami: setting or receiving that object should be the very first thing that happens in each of your files. Also, this is a simplified version. You can create a lot more complex solutions for this problem.

Comment: I agree this is the best solution. There were also some experimentaion with export/import in JavaScript ([see this page](http://hatayservices.com/books/Javascript/JavaScriptStatements.html#stmtexport)) but saving themethods/object on a global object (like window) is the BEST way...

Comment: I agree that this is a good solution, but it is not strictly *necessary* to create this object (so I disagree with "you need to").  A function outside of `$(document).ready(function() { });` and other namespaces will be globally available on the page.